# Selenium WebDriver set Attribute having webelement

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Currently I have a problem - I want to switch out of current frame to parent. Application have a lot of of inner frames, so using driver.switchTo().defaultContent() is not the case. In this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/group/webdriver/browse_thread/thread/66658caf429821e6?pli=1) possible solution is suggested - you should remember all frames you visited and and iterate over them from the top using

> driver.switchTo().defaultContent()

The main problem is in that fact, that in my application I, sometimes, forced to use switching to frames located by xpath and other locators - use switch by WebElement. And as it is already mentioned in discussion above after switching all located WebElement becomes invalid and can't be used for switching. So I should have some way to find this element inside frame again. Although i can locate index of this frame element executing some js calls(i.e `(WebElement)executeScript("window.frames[i]").equals(myWebElement)`), but it is not the case as index may change when some frames deleted from page. Either I can try to find frame names and id's but they may not be specified.

So I see the only possible solution - set some attribute to frames that parent of currently selected - for Example attribute active with value true. Also I should be able to do this for all methods that can switch frame (there exist 3). In all methods I can receive WebElement representing frame, but as far as I know to change attribute value you should execute some js code. So the problem is how to locate current WebElement in js.

Thanks for reading this all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at this code snippet above.that's the best way you can locate the current element in Js
passing the element as an argumet to execute script and referring to it in js using arguments[0]

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
String contents = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element);
```

Answer (score 0):

you would have to implement a custom logic using javascript

if the element has id then you can use the findElementById() method available in javascript else use the findElementsByName() and then iterate over the array and match other properties to narrow down to your element

Comment: you could try

webElement.setId("someValue") method to set an identifier for the the webelement and then in your javascript you can easily say

elem = document.findElementById("someValue"); elem.Value ="somethingElse";

if the element does not have its own id